# Create a log-based metrics that keeps track of the delta between 2 logs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, metrics, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

Let's say I have 3 application that works together, and use pub-sub to send messages for the "management".
Let's say that there is a "transaction id" created at the start and passed through the applications, and written in logs.

I will have the logs like following:

```
app1 - transactionIdX - started - timestamp01
app1 - transactionIdX - ended - timestamp02
app2 - transactionIdX - started - timestamp03
app1 - transactionIdY - started - timestamp04
app1 - transactionIdY - ended - timestamp05
app2 - transactionIdX - ended - timestamp06
app3 - transactionIdX - started - timestamp07
app2 - transactionIdY - started - timestamp08
app2 - transactionIdY - ended - timestamp09
app3 - transactionIdX - ended - timestamp10
app3 - transactionIdY - started - timestamp11
app3 - transactionIdY - ended - timestamp12
```

I would like to have a metrics that exposes this kind of information:

- transactionIdX - at time timestamp10

  - in app1 - needed (timestamp02-timestamp01) seconds
  - in app2 - needed (timestamp06-timestamp03) seconds
  - in app3 - needed (timestamp10-timestamp07) seconds
  - in total - needed (timestamp10-timestamp01) seconds
- transactionIdY - at time timestamp12

  - in app1 - needed (timestamp05-timestamp04) seconds
  - in app2 - needed (timestamp09-timestamp08) seconds
  - in app3 - needed (timestamp12-timestamp11) seconds
  - in total - needed (timestamp12-timestamp04) seconds

Is there a way to build a log-based metrics that offers this kind of information?

Comment: It would seem that you could easily write a script in Python/Ruby/Whatever to extract this from the log data, but I guess you mean something else. Perhaps you could try to make the question more explicit?

Comment: My real question is if there is a way to do it without external applications, simply using the metrics creation api

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, this cannot be done by only using the logs-based metrics API. The logs-based metrics pipeline does not maintain state between two log entries, so you cannot capture two values and formulate a query to capture the difference between the two.

I see two possible workarounds:

1. Instrument your app to keep stats about transaction latency, and output that in logs and capture it using logs-based metrics.
2. Perform such computation at query time with scripts using something like [Cloud Datalab](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/datalab/quickstart-datalab) which integrates with Stackdriver.

*Disclaimer: I am an engineer in Google Stackdriver.*

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently coding a sample solution. Will post it on other thread: [Latency SLO from logs on GCP Cloud Logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69336676/latency-slo-from-logs-on-gcp-cloud-logging)